# Maps between short exact sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, representation-theory

Suppose I have a short exact sequence of modules $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$. Let $A' \subseteq A$ and $C' \subseteq C$ be submodules and suppose I have a short exact sequence $0 \to A'\to B'\to C'\to 0$. Then I have the following diagram:
$$
  \require{AMScd}
  \begin{CD}
    0 @>>> A'   @>>> B'   @>>>C' @>>> 0  \\
    @.     @VVV      @.   @VVV        @. \\
    0 @>>> A    @>>> B    @>>>C  @>>> 0
  \end{CD}
$$

I know in general there is no map $B' \to B$ that would make the diagram commute, but are there sufficient conditions for such a map to exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, given a diagram
$$\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
\varepsilon'\colon & 0 & \to & A' & \to & B' & \to & C' & \to & 0\\
&&& \phantom{\alpha}\downarrow\alpha&&&& \phantom{\gamma}\downarrow\gamma\\
\varepsilon\colon & 0 & \to & A & \to & B & \to & C & \to & 0
\end{array}$$
you can fill it in with a map $\beta\colon B'\to B$ if and only if the pushout $\alpha\varepsilon'$ equals the pullback $\varepsilon\gamma$ as extensions in $\mathrm{Ext}^1(C',A)$. Note that this doesn't required $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ to be monomorphisms.

Note that, in your situation, the pullback yields a submodule $B_2\leq B$ (the preimage of $C'$). Also, if there is such a map, then $B'$ would necessarily be (isomorphic to) a submodule of $B$.

Comment: If $alpha$ is the identity map, then how is the consequence?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is the identity, then this becomes: there exists $\beta$ making the diagram commute if and only if $\varepsilon’$ equals the pullback $\varepsilon\gamma$.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much!